Why does the line wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("loader"))); take too long to execute? Open to better alternatives
I am currently doing an internship at a company, and I have to test an app that reacts differently each time. I run my test case, it passes, and 5 minutes later, I run it again, and it fails. What frustrates me is why the compiler cannot find or interact with the element sometimes. Additionally, there are some input boxes where I was unable to use sendKeys, and I had to combine it with JavascriptExecutor and explicit waits.
While trying to find a more compatible solution that I can use for most input boxes, I found this line of code:
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("loader")));
It works for almost all situations, but this time, although WebDriverWait is set to a maximum of 2 seconds, my test cases run very slowly. One simple test case takes around 2 minutes.
Can someone please explain why this line takes too long to execute, and are there any better alternatives?

2 seconds isn't all that long.  You need to debug a bit and make sure to try/catch all driver method calls so you can output the exceptions.  These will help you.  It may be that the timeout exception is thrown after 2 seconds, meaning it either didn't find the element, or it's still visible in the dom.  Then next procedures may also be failing.... as is, the question needs more code, exceptions and/or markup from the DOM to be answerable.
